# Can't shut down the computer. It only reboots

Tags: shutdown

```
sudo halt -p
```

makes a reboot

```
sudo halt
```

stops but not power off

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

reboots.

Based on the advice from Bug #985471, I modified `/etc/default/grub`, changing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="reboot=pci quiet splash"` and I have installed `laptop-mode-tools`, but cannot power off the computer reboot always.

```
3.8.0-35-generic (#50~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 4 17:25:51 UTC 2013) / xorg:1.13.3 (16 October 2013  04:46:41PM)
```

Can anyone help me to shutdown my PC completely?

Comment: can you be bit clear what your problem is.

Comment: @user229167 r u dead? what happened with your shutdown?

Answer (score 1):

Shutdown ubuntu

```
sudo shutdown -h
```

reboot

```
sudo reboot
```